# Chartjs - Shift line plot to the right?

Tags: chart.js

In Chartjs, is there any way to shift the line plot to the right 1 tick? Right now the line starts from the y-axis and as the result at the origin, there are labels from both x and y axis that does not look that nice. I attach the screenshot

[image]

Ideally I would like the `09-2016` to move to the right a litte. Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an empty label and to the start of the labels array and a `null` value to the start of your dataArray to shift it a bit

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [null, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'red',
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks it works. Btw is there any way to reduce the distance between the first tick in x-axis (here it is `red`) and the y-axis? Ideally I would like to have just a small gap between the start of the line and the y-axis.

Comment: No, not with my solution

Comment: I found the solution. For whomever is interested, set `offset:true` (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/category/)